# Is it possible to stretch the height of images so that each row fully complements the conainer?

Tags: css, reactjs, layout, column-count

Im trying to implement responsive masonry grid with react and css(I can not use any library whatsoever). I came across a very clever solution which is the css column-count property. The question is ,however, if theres any possibility to stretch, adjust the content of the div container (in my code reffered to as masonryGrid) so that its completely filled up. I know about the strech in flex display however that is not an option here due to the css column-count property.

Single element of masonry grid:

```
    const MasonryCell = (props: any) => {

    return(
        <img src={props.src} alt="cat" style={{width:'100%'}}></img>
    )
}

export {MasonryCell}
```

Masonry grid:

```
import { useMasonryGrid } from "../../helpers/hooks/useMasonryGrid"

const MasonryGrid = (props: any)=> {
    const {masonryGridRef, numberOfColumns} = useMasonryGrid()

return (
<div ref={masonryGridRef} style={{columnCount: props.numberOfColumns, columnGap:0, maxWidth:1200, margin: '0 auto', fontSize: 0}}>
    {props.children}
</div>
)
}

export {MasonryGrid}
```

App.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { MasonryGrid } from "./components/MasonryGrid/MasonryGrid";
import { MasonryCell } from "./components/MasonryCell";
import "./App.css";

const DUMMY_DATA = [
  "https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/7on.gif",
  "https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/8k7.jpg",
  "https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/9h2.jpg",
  "https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/9qj.jpg",
  "https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/a73.gif",
  "https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/aht.jpg",
  "https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/cua.jpg",
  "https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/dut.jpg",
  "https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/e64.jpg",
  "https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/MTg5NzA3Mw.jpg",
  "https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/MTk2NzgzNw.jpg",
  "https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/MjAyNDc5Ng.jpg",
  "https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/y9sSXTyxC.jpg",
  "https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/2b2pFY0-t.jpg",
  "https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/fW9wukL9G.jpg",
  "https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/YLTXM6XYQ.jpg",
  "https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/r0rerbt2U.jpg",
  "https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/S7CZYvR0-.png",
  "https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/11gBRYnGK.png",
];

function App() {
  return (
    <MasonryGrid>
      {DUMMY_DATA.map((data, index) => <MasonryCell src={data} key={index}/>)}
    </MasonryGrid>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: I'll add one more explanation. Width is not an issue here. Only height is the dimension Im trying to adjust, so that the pictures end in one line.

Comment: Do you actually want images to stretch or do you want, say, an adjustment to be made to each image in a short column , for example using cover and so clipping some images?

Comment: I want pictures to cover not only 100% of width of the container but also its height.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but what is needed is to know whether you want images to be stretched vertically or to be expanded and cropped to make images that are tall enough to fill a column.

Comment: I think the most desired solution would be if images in one column alltogether have insufficient height to cover the column, then they all stretch accordingly to how much space is left, so that not only the last picture in given column is stretched a lot, but all img's are stretchet a lil bit.